# Running multiple Qt tests in eclipse

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt

I am setting up tests for a big Qt (4.8.x) project and want to run qt unit tests inside Eclipse (JUNO). Therefor I installed C/C++ Unit Testing Support. I created a sub project which contains 3 test cases in 3 classes/files. Since I am able to build a test application I added a new "Run Configuration" to eclipse choosing the "Qt Tests Runner".

Now I am able to start/run the tests in Eclipse but Eclipse only shows the resuls of one class and then stops with the error:

> XML parse error:: The procession instruction target matching
>   "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

I ran the Qt test binary with -xml and found out that the application output is 3 complete xml documents instead of one. I think thats the problem but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple test classes run from the same executable? As far as I know every time you call `QTest::qExec()` QTest treats it as a complete test.

I think what they were aiming for with QTest was one executable per test class instead. I haven't found a way around this yet, but you may get away with either doing what QTest wants (one executable per test class) or switching to googletest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the project is very big, so I have to run many test cases at once. I am using Qt Creator and included "CONFIG+=testcase" into each test case ".pro" file. If a test fails the build finishs with an error - thats ok, but sometimes it takes a long time to find the failed test inside the console. Therefor I wanted to start the test with eclipse.